# django admin action checkbox not showing in chaneglist_view

Tags: django, django-admin

My problem here is, In django admin list view the action checkboxes are not being displayed when I use `changelist_view` in admin. I have given the `admin.py` code below. Please go through it and provide me a solution.

```
def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    if request.user == 'admin':
        self.list_display_links = ('project', )
        self.list_display = ('project', 'task_name', 'assignee_role', 'assignee_name', )
    else:
        self.list_display_links = ('task_name', )
        self.list_display = ( 'task_name', 'project', 'priority', )
    return super(ModelAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context = None)
```

Here what I want to achieve is to change the `list_display` and `list_display_links` fields based on user. I'm achieving it when I use `changelist_view`. But the action checkboxes are being hidden for all users when I do this.

So how to display action checkboxes when using `changelist_view` or how to achieve the above things without using `changelist_view`. Please provide a  solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution after going through the django installation source file `django/contrib/admin/options.py`. To display action checkbox when using `changelist_view` include it in `list_display`. But I couldn't figure out why it is being hidden when using `changelist_view`.

```
def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    if request.user == 'admin':
        self.list_display_links = ('project', )
        self.list_display = ('action_checkbox', 'project', 'task_name', 'assignee_role', 'assignee_name', )
    else:
        self.list_display_links = ('task_name', )
        self.list_display = ( 'task_name', 'project', 'priority', )
return super(ModelAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context = None)
```

So here the action checkbox will be displayed only if the current logged in user is admin since it is included in `list_display`.

Comment: I added 'action_checkbox' like you suggested above, but I don't see it in my queryset results. What do you mean by user has to be an admin in order to see it?